# Why cant I move this object to the top?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using layers, and in the layer order I have one object with lines and gradients, that won't stay on top. I have tired several ways to get it to the top. Moving the layer to top, cutting and past on top. starting a new file and adding each layer in order. This object comes out on the bottom no matter what order the layers are and no matter what layer it is pasted into.

Illustrator CS6

Comment: Could you show us a screen shot or example what you want to achieve please

Comment: Is `Paste Remembers Layers` checked in the **Layer Panel Menu**??

Answer (score 1):

Apart everything you tried do, check if you are using blending mode. If yes, try reverting it to "Normal"